# Gem development with Bundler: include or exclude Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

I'm developing a gem locally. It's a command-line utility that only has test dependencies, and my Gemfile looks like this:

```
source :rubygems
gemspec

group :test do
  gem "cucumber"
  gem "aruba"
  gem "rspec"
end
```

My gemspec looks like this:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # authorship stuff...
  s.files = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
end
```

That's the default gemspec created by Bundler. I know we're supposed to keep Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in source control, but I'm wondering about including them in the packaged gem through the `Gem::Specification#files` attribute. Are there arguments for/against including Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in the distributed gem? It seems weird or at least unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yehuda Katz just blogged on this topic! : [Clarifying the Roles of the .gemspec and Gemfile](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/)

Comment: That post actually prompted my question, but I read it before he added the TL;DR clarifying conditions for gem development. Thanks for pointing me back to it.